# is there any chance an exception happens during variable definition?

Tags: c++, multithreading, exception

```
class ThreadGuard {
public:
    ThreadGuard(std::thread &t_): t(t_) {}
    ~ThreadGuard()
    {
        if(t.joinable()) 
            t.join();
    }
private:
    std::thread &t;
};

void func()
{
    std::thread my_thread(f);
    ThreadGuard thread_guard(my_thread);
}
```

I try to use the ThreadGuard object to guarantee that the func won't exit until the thread terminates normally. But what if an exception happens just before the thread_guard object is created.

Comment: It should be fine. If an exception throwed, means the thread construction failed, then the thread shouldn't run, the function should exit. Is it right?

Comment: **−1** The `if(t.joinable)` is **not the real code**.

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake. It should be `if(t.joinable())`.

Comment: The thread construction succeed, the thread_guard construction failed. The thread has already run.

Answer (score 0):

The point of RAII is for the resource acquiring object to actually own the resource. Your `ThreadGuard` still can't guarantee that the thread is actually guarded. You'll want something more like:

```
class ThreadGuard {
    std::thread t;

public:
    ~ThreadGuard() {
        if (t.joinable()) t.join();
    }

    // constructors and assignment as appropriate to actually
    // initialize the thread object
};
```

That way, you can just write:

```
ThreadGuard thread_guard(f);
```

and not worry.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't quite understand how to implement an  appropriate constructor. I guess the only right way to initialize the member `std::thread t` is inheriting from class `std::thread` and calling it's constructor in my own class's constructor directly. If it's the case, I need to pass an parameter of type..., I don't know how to call it, function, callable object, or something like that, to my constructor. It's a little complicate for me.